# How to change the default port in react js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, create-react-app

I could able to start react js with default port 3000. But, when I customised the port to 4200, `"start": "PORT=4200 react-scripts start"`(Just changed in the package.json), I am not able to start the react js application.

```
'PORT' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! todo-app@0.1.0 start: `PORT=4200 react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the todo-app@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional lo
ging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

Comment: I guess you're using Windows - that syntax is how to set an env var in *nix.

Answer (score 20):

to start APP on another port run the following npm command

`npm start --port 3002`

or to config in package use

replace the start command with below

```
"start": "set PORT=3006 && react-scripts start"
```

Comment: @ Manpreet Its worked !! Thank you .

Comment: @javalearning . welcome

Comment: It worked for me

Comment: Thanks, It worked for me also specially &&

Answer (score 12):

An other option that was not mentioned in the other answer would be to create a `.env` file in the root directory and put `PORT=4200` in it. It will automatically be loaded in your environment variables.